Find angular velocity of the object knowing some other strange velocity vector
I'm trying to solve a problem in physics/maths but don't get how to express the sentence about distance change $1 \frac{\text{km}}{\text{min}}$ in the language of formula/expression of physics. I don't simply understand what this condition could give me in this task. Hope you can direct me in my learning.
The problem is following:

The building is located on a circular road with a radius of $5 \text{ km}$. Alex lives on the same circular road at a point diametrically opposite to the building. Alex drives to work by car on the ring road. It is known that he travels in such a way that the distance (in a straight line) between him and the building decreases at a speed of $1 \text{ km}$ per minute.
What is the angular velocity $V$ between the building and Alex at the moment when the angle between them is $\frac{\pi}{2}$? Find the speed in radians per minute.



It can help to parameterize the position of the car. A natural choice is the angle of the car along the road.

I am not clear on what "the angle between the building and Alex" means.  We need a 3rd point to define the angle.  Would that be Alex's house?  In which case, if the angle between Alex's house, the building, and Alex is $\frac {\pi}{2}$ then Alex is driving straight toward the building.

@user317176 If that is the angle, then Alex would be at the building, no? ;)

@DavidK I tend to agree with your guess. The terms in this question should be clarified.

By the way, the distance that is said to decrease by $1$ km/min is not a "strange velocity vector" as stated in the question's title. It is not a vector at all, at least not in the ordinary sense used in physics.

hey everyone! I edited the content of the problem a bit and added a picture for it so the angle mentioned is clear. hope it helps

Let's say the ring road is represented by the equation $x^2+y^2=25$. According to the picture in your post, Alex's starting point seems to be at $(5,0)$, and he travels counterclockwise to reach his destination at $(-5,0)$. Now let's draw a right triangle with one leg on the $x$-axis, another leg extending perpendicularly upwards, and the hypotenuse connecting the two ends.

The purple point shows Alex's position on the path, represented by the coordinates $\left(x,\sqrt{25-x^2}\right)$. Since the hypotenuse of this triangle represents the distance between Alex and his destination, we will call the hypotenuse $D$. We can figure out the value of $D$ using the Pythagorean Theorem:
$D=\sqrt{(x-(-5))^2+(\sqrt{25-x^2})^2}=\underline{\sqrt{10x+50}}$
We also know that $D$ has a rate of change of $-1\,\frac{\text{km}}{\text{min}}$, so we can differentiate $D$ and make it equal to $-1$:
$$\frac{dD}{dt}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{10x+50}}\cdot 10\,\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}=-1$$
$$\frac{dD}{dt}=\boxed{\frac{5}{\sqrt{10x+50}}\;\frac{dx}{dt}=-1}$$
Since $\frac{dD}{dt}$ is constant, the term $\frac{dx}{dt}$ changes depending on Alex's position on the path. In this case, we are using the instant when the angle between Alex and his destination is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, or in other words, when Alex's position is at $x=0$, shown below:

This means we can plug $x=0$ into the equation for $\frac{dD}{dt}$ to solve for $\frac{dx}{dt}$:
$$\frac{5}{\sqrt{10(0)+50}}\;\frac{dx}{dt}=-1$$
$$\frac{5}{\sqrt{50}}\;\frac{dx}{dt}=-1$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\boxed{-\frac{\sqrt{50}}{5}}$$
The last step is to find the rate of change of the angle made at the origin by Alex's position coordinate and the $x$-axis, which looks like this (for a randomly chosen position of Alex):

Since we know Alex's coordinates $\left(x,\sqrt{25-x^2}\right)$, we can use the $\arctan$ function to represent the angle $\theta$:
$\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}{x}\right)$
Now we differentiate $\theta$ to find its rate of change (I didn't include the long calculations):
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\boxed{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\;\frac{dx}{dt}}$$
Since we know that $x=0$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{\sqrt{50}}{5}$, we can plug in those values to get the final rate of change of $\theta$:
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{25-(0)^2}}\cdot -\frac{\sqrt{50}}{5}$$
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{\sqrt{50}}{25}\approx \boxed{0.283\;\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{min}}}$$
Edit: After looking at K. Jiang's answer, I realized that my answer was exactly double of theirs, which leads me to believe that although my process was valid, I made a computation error somewhere. Hopefully I (or someone else) can catch that error and fix it up soon.

I think you did everything correctly here. We had different interpretations of the "angular velocity between the building and Alex". I took it to mean the rate of change of $\angle ABO$, where $A$ is Alex, $B$ is the building, and $O$ is the origin; you took it to mean the rate of change of $\angle AOB$. Your interpretation might be the intended one; it is hard to know for sure because the question is still not completely clear.

@K.Jiang Ah, I see what you’re saying. Thanks for clearing that up!

From kinematics, we have that Alex's velocity is
$$\vec{v}_A = \vec{v}_O + \vec{\omega}_\mathcal{B} \times \vec{r}_{O \to A} + \vec{v}_{A / \mathcal{B}}$$
where we let $\vec{v}_O = \vec{0}$ be the building and $\mathcal{B}$ be the frame attached to an imaginary line connecting the building and Alex. Assume the building is at the point $-R \vec{e}_x$ (Alex starts at $R \vec{e}_x$). What we are given is that $|\vec{v}_{A / \mathcal{B}}| = v_0$, the rate at which Alex approaches the building. When the angle difference between Alex and the building is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, the displacement $\vec{r}_{O \to A} = R \vec{e}_x + R \vec{e}_y$, and the relative velocity $\vec{v}_{A / \mathcal{B}} = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} v_0 \vec{e}_x - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} v_0 \vec{e}_y$ (because we know that the magnitude must be $v_0$, and the direction must be (anti-)parallel to $\vec{r}_{O \to A}$).
Since the motion is planar, $\omega_\mathcal{B} = \omega \vec{e}_z$. Therefore, $\vec{\omega}_\mathcal{B} \times \vec{r}_{O \to A} = -R \omega \vec{e}_x + R \omega \vec{e}_y$.
Therefore, we have
$$\vec{v}_A = -\left( R \omega + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} v_0 \right) \vec{e}_x + \left( R \omega - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} v_0 \right) \vec{e}_y$$
We know that when the angle difference between Alex and the building is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, Alex is at the top of the circular path, and so he has no velocity in $\vec{e}_y$. This then directly gives that $R \omega - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} v_0 = 0 \implies \omega = \boxed{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \frac{v_0}{R}}$.
Substituting your values,
$$\omega = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \frac{1 \text{ kpm}}{5 \text{ km}} \approx \boxed{0.141 \frac{\text{rad}}{\text{min}}}$$
EDIT: Note that the angular velocity calculated above is the rate of change of the angle $\theta$ of the line connecting the building to Alex, which is what I thought was being asked before the question was edited. It seems that the rate of change of the central angle $\theta_c$ was desired. Of course, they can be related because we have by exterior angles on the isosceles triangle that
$$\theta_c = 2 \theta$$
giving
$$\omega_c = 2 \omega = \sqrt{2} \frac{v_0}{R} \approx 0.283 \frac{\text{rad}}{\text{min}}$$
